# Raspberry Pi Able To Be Seen On Local Network, But Not On Public Network

Tags: apache-http-server, home-networking, raspberry-pi

sorry if this is a really noobie question, I am just getting into networking and running a small website kind of as a hobby. So right now I have a Raspberry Pi running the latest Raspbian Stretch distro and Apache2. My ISP (RCN) blocks port 80 so I thought I could use port 8080. I have ports forwarded on my Motorola router and I have Apache listening for 8080.

I can see the website from a computer that is located on the local network, but when I use my public IP and specify the port I don't see anything. Even canyouseeme.org confirms that the port is not open.

Is this an issue of some firewall on my router blocking connections or my ISP or is my Apache not correctly set up?

Any input is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would review your router configuration for the port forward of 8080.  If canyou seeme says it isn't open, then that's the likely culprit.  In some routers it is a two step process to port forward.  First create the service, then assign it to a host.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked the manual for my specific router (MG7540) and followed all of the steps. It never mentions assigning it to a host...

Comment: Assigning to a host means telling the router where to forward the packets for the specific port to. In your case that would be the (local) IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Oh ok, then I have done that. I can access the server just fine on the local network using the public IP, I just can't access it from outside the network.

Comment: Maybe try a different port

Comment: I've tried 8080, 8000 and 82. Are there any special ones I should try? I know my ISP blocks 80 and 25